# DataTable doesn't show data

Tags: asp.net-core, datatables

I am trying to use Datatable and I have an issue with Datatable populating data in my .net core project.When the page is loaded, DataTable records are empty.According to the picture below:

[image]

Controller:

```
 public IActionResult ShowCategory()
        {
            return View();
        }


 public IActionResult CategoryList()
        {
            try
            {
                var draw = HttpContext.Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault();
                // Skiping number of Rows count
                var start = Request.Form["start"].FirstOrDefault();
                // Paging Length 10,20
                var length = Request.Form["length"].FirstOrDefault();
                // Sort Column Name
                var sortColumn = Request.Form["columns[" + Request.Form["order[0][column]"].FirstOrDefault() + "][name]"].FirstOrDefault();
                // Sort Column Direction ( asc ,desc)
                var sortColumnDirection = Request.Form["order[0][dir]"].FirstOrDefault();
                // Search Value from (Search box)
                var searchValue = Request.Form["search[value]"].FirstOrDefault()   
                
               var data = _categoryRepository.GetCategories();

            
                return Json(new { draw = 1, recordsFiltered = 4, recordsTotal = 4, data = data });
         
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        
            
         }
```

Due to a problem with the code, I have now passed the draw and ... to View as a hardcode.

```
GetCategories() method:
public List<CategoryViewModel> GetCategories()
        {
            

            var query = _CategoryRepo.GetAll();

            var q = query.Select(s => new CategoryViewModel
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                CaregoryParentId = s.CaregoryParentId,
                Priority = s.Priority,
                Title = s.Title
            }).ToList();

         
            return q;
        }
```

view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/css/admin/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js "></script>

<div class="container">
    <br />
    <div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>CaregoryParentId</th>
                    <th>Priority</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

        $(document).ready(function ()
        {

            $("#example").DataTable({
                "processing": true, // for show progress bar
                "serverSide": true, // for process server side
                "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
                "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Admin/Category/CategoryList",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "json"
               
                    //"success": function (data) {
                    //    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    //}
                },
                "columnDefs":
                [{
                    "targets": [0],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": false
                }],
                { "data": "Id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Title", "name": "Title", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "CaregoryParentId", "name": "CaregoryParentId", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Priority", "name": "Priority", "autoWidth": true },
                
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta)
                        { return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/DemoGrid/Edit/' + full.CustomerID + '">Edit</a>'; }
                    },
                    {
                        data: null, render: function (data, type, row)
                        {
                            return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteData('" + row.CustomerID + "'); >Delete</a>";
                        }
                    },
                ]

            });
        });


    function DeleteData(CustomerID)
        {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ...?"))
            {
                Delete(CustomerID);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


        function Delete(CustomerID)
    {
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "DemoGrid/Delete";

        $.post(url, { ID: CustomerID }, function (data)
                {
                    if (data)
                    {
                        oTable = $('#example').DataTable();
                        oTable.draw();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Something Went Wrong!");
                    }
                });
    }

</script>
```

when I debug, I receive data in Ajax success function, but it is not shown in the table.
can anybody help me?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I debug, I receive data in Ajax success function, but it is not
> shown in the table.

[image]

From the result above we can see, server return serializes JSON with camel case names by default.

- `Id` => `id`
- `Title` => `title`
- `CaregoryParentId` => `caregoryParentId`
- `Priority` => `priority`

But in your script, "data" is set as "Id".

> Solution

**Use the codes below to avoid camel case names by default.**

```
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(opts => opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
```

**Codes of JS**

```
   $(document).ready(function ()
    {

        $("#example").DataTable({
            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process server side
            "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Admin/Category/CategoryList",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json",

                //"success": function (data) {
                //    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                //}
            },
            "columnDefs":
            [{
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Title", "name": "Title", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "CaregoryParentId", "name": "CaregoryParentId", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Priority", "name": "Priority", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) { return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/DemoGrid/Edit/' + full.CustomerID + '">Edit</a>'; }
                },
                {
                    data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteData('" + row.CustomerID + "'); >Delete</a>";
                    }
                }
            ]

        });
    });
```

> Test of result

[image]

Comment: Hi Michael. I asked a question in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64187211/multi-tabs-datatable-doesnt-display-data . can you help me?Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, @n.e, just back from holiday and glad to see the question you post above has been answered.