# Multi tabs datatable doesn't display data

Tags: asp.net-core, datatables

I have created multi tab datatable in .net core project, but the table doesn't show data.
I debugged and return data in controller action and in Ajax success function is ok
but it doesn't display in the table and and there are no errors in the console.

can anybody help me?

Thanks so much.

controller:

```
  public IActionResult GetCategoryById(int id, int languageId = 0)
        {
            var categoryViewModel = _categoryRepository.GetCategory(id, languageId);
            CategoryViewModel category = new CategoryViewModel()
            {
                 Id = categoryViewModel.Id,
                 Title = categoryViewModel.Title,
                 CaregoryParentId  = categoryViewModel.CaregoryParentId,
                 Priority = categoryViewModel.Priority

            };
            return Json(category);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            ViewData["categoryId"] = id;
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="~/css/dataTable/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/dataTable/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/dataTable/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            $.fn.dataTable.tables({ visible: true, api: true }).columns.adjust();
        });

        $('table.table').DataTable({
            ajax:
            {
                "url": "/Admin/Category/GetCategoryById/"+ @ViewData["categoryId"] ,
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [

                { "data": "id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "title", "name": "Title", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "caregoryParentId", "name": "CaregoryParentId", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "priority", "name": "Priority", "autoWidth": true },

            ],

            scrollY: 200,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging: false
        });
        $('#myTable2').DataTable().search('New York').draw();
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body class="dt-example dt-example-bootstrap">
    <div class="container">
        <section>

            <div class="demo-html"></div>
            <div>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#tab-table1" data-toggle="tab">Table 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#tab-table2" data-toggle="tab">Table 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-table1">
                        <table id="myTable1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Id</th>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                    <th>CaregoryParentId</th>
                                    <th>Priority</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-table2">
                        <table id="myTable2" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Id</th>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                    <th>CaregoryParentId</th>
                                    <th>Priority</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are two errors to cause this issue.

First, the `jquery datatable` needs the json which field name is `data` , because you should receive the json in `columns` by reading `data`.

Another one, the `jquery datatable` should get the data of **collection** instead of one data, although you only have one data to return, you should put it in the **list of CategoryViewModel**.

Change your `GetCategoryById` method as follow:

```
   public IActionResult GetCategoryById(int id, int languageId = 0)
    {
        var categoryViewModel = _categoryRepository.GetCategory(id, languageId);
        CategoryViewModel category = new CategoryViewModel()
        {
             Id = categoryViewModel.Id,
             Title = categoryViewModel.Title,
             CaregoryParentId  = categoryViewModel.CaregoryParentId,
             Priority = categoryViewModel.Priority

        };
        List<CategoryViewModel> categories = new List<CategoryViewModel>();
        categories.Add(category);
        return Json(new { data = categories });
    }
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I also put "datasrc" = " " in Ajax and pass the list of CategoryViewmodel and I tested, but the data is still not shown in the table.

Comment: @n.e, can you should me what your current code? And do you add `data`  in the returned json: `return Json(new { data = categories });` ?

Comment: My current code is what I sent and I put the GetCategoryById method as you sent it. Yes, I added the data.

Comment: I get response in the success function but it is not displayed in the table.

Comment: @n.e, check the `console` tab of F12 to confirm if there are any error messages.
If there is no error, please debug your acquired code to confirm whether `GetCategoryById` method has been obtained from the database and returned the corresponding data.

Comment: I debugged it before. The id is passed to the GetCategoryById action and the action returns a list of categories. When I do not use as a multi-tab, the answer is displayed in the datatable.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yongqing.  Problem solved, I delete "datasrc" = "" from ajax and data was shown in the table.